# AWS S3 CLI : Check Validate Inside Automatically?

Tags: aws

We're using "s3api put-object" and explicitly checking Hash MD5 to make sure the file uploaded to S3 correctly (Unless the upload file is less than 5 GB)

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucketname --key test.txt --body c:\temp\test.txt --content-encoding base64 --content-md5 **********
```

I'm just wondering if s3 cp commands also checking MD5 header inside itself, according to following reference.
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/topic/s3-faq.html

When we simply command "aws s3 cp c:\temp\test.txt s3://mybucketname/YYYY" on CLI, if the hash value doesn't match, then CLI re-try 5 times -- as long as my understanding is correct.

The reason why I ask this, we will not allow to use s3api put-object in our new job controller system any more and I'm just wondering we can expect or not, s3 cp CLI command validations.

Any advice would be so much appreciated again. Thank you.
Sachiko

Comment: this would be a question for StackOverflow, not DBA.SE.

Comment: @nateirvin Thanks for your advice!